# How to reverse a string without using reverse() function, wanting the reverse to be word by word not from last index to the first index in swift

Tags: ios, swift, reverse

```
let word = "String to be reverse"

var reversed = ""
for char in word.characters {
    reversed.insert(char, at: reversed.startIndex)
}
print(reversed)
```

This returns : "esrever eb ot gnirtS"
What i'm trying to do is like this "ngirtS ot eb esrever"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use enumerateSubstrings in range using options `.byWords`, get all substrings range and replace them with the substring of the same range reversed:

```
let string = "String to be reverse"

var ranges: [Range<String.Index>] = []
string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { _, range, _, _ in
    ranges.append(range)
}
var result = string
for range in ranges {
    var newWord = string[range]
    var reversed = ""
    while !newWord.isEmpty {
        reversed.append(newWord.removeLast())
    }
    result.replaceSubrange(range, with: reversed)
}
print(result) // "gnirtS ot eb esrever"
```